# Django - Two Different Views from Different Apps into a single Template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Django beginner here.

I am trying to make a an app for where users can make connections, post stuff, chat, etc. There are two user types - `Parents` and `Child`. For this I extended the `AbstractBaseUser` model and created two another models - `Parent` and `Child` with a `OneToOne` link to the `User`.

```py
#accounts/models.py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=DefaultModel.MAX_LENGTH, unique=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=DefaultModel.MAX_LENGTH, unique=False)

    profile_photo = models.ImageField(default='uploads/profile/default_profile.jpg', upload_to=content_image_name)
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(default='uploads/profile/default_cover.jpg', upload_to=content_image_name)
    username = AutoSlugField(populate_from='first_name', unique=True, sep='.')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="Nothing to see here !")
    

    is_child = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # storing timestamps for users.
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    CHOICES = (('M','Male'),('F','Female'),('O','Other'))
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/{}".format(self.username)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Child(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self',
        blank=True,
        related_name='friends',
        db_column='friends',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)


class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    connections = models.ManyToManyField('self',
        blank=True,
        related_name='connections',
        db_column='connections',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

As you can see a `Child` can only be a friend with another `Child` and a `Parent` can only connect with a `Parent`.
Basically I have two apps - Feeds for handling posts and accounts for handling accounts. There is a page for displaying the current users (`/childs/` for `Child` and `/parents/` for `Parent`) and another for friends (`/friends/` for `Child` and `/connections/` for `Parent`).

In the homepage (`/home`) of the apps there are two sidebars - one for showing users whom the `request.user` can send friend request to and another for displaying the friends of `request.user`. Since there is a single url (`/home`) for both user types, therefore the strategy is :

1. Make a base ListView for displaying both current users and friends.
2. Inherit it for the individual users and friends page.
3. Inherit it for `home.html` for `/home`.

```py
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UserList(ListView):
    model = User

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_child:
            childs = Child.objects.exclude(user=self.request.user.child)   
            sent_requests =  ChildFriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=self.request.user.child)
            recv_requests = ChildFriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=self.request.user.child)
            friends = self.request.user.child.friends.all()
            recv_from = [i.from_user for i in recv_requests]
            users = [i for i in childs if i not in friends and i not in recv_from]
            sent_to = [ i.to_user for i in sent_requests]
            context['users'] = users
            context['sent'] = sent_to
            context['friends'] = friends
            context['recv_requests'] = recv_requests
        elif self.request.user.is_parent:
            parents = Parent.objects.exclude(user=self.request.user.parent)   
            sent_requests =  ParentConnectionRequest.objects.filter(from_user=self.request.user.parent)
            recv_requests =  ParentConnectionRequest.objects.filter(to_user=self.request.user.parent)
            connections = self.request.user.parent.connections.all()
            recv_from = [i.from_user for i in recv_requests]
            users = [i for i in parents if i not in connections and i not in recv_from]
            sent_to = [ i.to_user for i in sent_requests]
            context['users'] = users
            context['sent'] = sent_to
            context['connections'] = connections
            context['recv_requests'] = recv_requests
        return context

class ChildList(UserList):
    template_name = "account/child/childs_list.html"

class FriendList(UserList):
    template_name = "account/child/friend_list.html"

class ParentList(UserList):
    template_name = "account/parent/parent_list.html"

class ConnectionList(UserList):
    template_name = "account/parent/connection_list.html"

class Sidebar(UserList):
    template_name = "feeds/home.html"
```

Now `views` of `Feeds` app also use `home.html` for it displaying feeds.

```py
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'feeds/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 10 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            liked = [i for i in Post.objects.all() if Like.objects.filter(user = self.request.user, post=i)]
            context['liked_post'] = liked
        return context
```

The problem here is that whenever `/friends` or `/childs` is accessed I can see the users but in the `/home` no user is shown although I can see the posts.

Here's `home.html`

```html
{% extends "feeds/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block friends_sidebar %}
                                    <div class="widget stick-widget">
                                        <h4 class="widget-title">People Nearby</h4>
                                        <ul class="followers">
                                        {% if users %}
                                        {% for user_p in users %}
                                            <li>
                                                <figure>
                                                    <a href="{{ user_p.user.get_absolute_url }}" title=""><img src="{{ user_p.user.profile_photo.url }}" width="40" height="40" alt=""></a>
                                                </figure>
                                                <div class="friend-meta">
                                                    <h4><a href="{{ user_p.user.get_absolute_url }}" title="">{{ user_p.user }}</a></h4>
                                            {% if not user_p in sent %}
                                                    <a href="/child/friend-request/send/{{ user_p.user.id }}/" title="" class="underline">Add Friend</a>
                                            {% else %}
                                                    <a href="/child/friend-request/cancel/{{ user_p.user.id }}/" title="" class="underline">Cancel Request</a>
                                            {% endif %}
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        {% else %}
                                            <p>No one is here !</p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I can only see :

```html
No one is here !
```

So the question is how can I go working around this ? Is it because two views are using the same template ?

I am using Django 3.2.9 and Python 3.8.

Comment: In UserList you fill the context with  'users' which you dont do in PostListView (see your get_context_data() ) and PostListView is not based on UserList but ListView

Comment: @Razenstein That's because UserList is for listing the users (of the same user type, i.e, a student account can only see a student) while PostListView is for listing the posts by any user (type).

Comment: @Razenstein Does that mean that I need to inherit UserList in PostListView ?

Comment: At least you need to add the users to the context as you do in the UserList Class. You need not to inherit but then add it in the get_context_data of PostListView

Comment: @Razenstein Thanks man, that worked like a charm ! Have a good day !

Comment: @Razenstein I inherited the `UserList` in `PostListView`, called `super()` in the `get_context_data` and that did it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Razenstein mentioned I needed to have the contexts of UserList in PostListView, so I inherited UserList in PostListView and that did it. Here's what was to be done :

```py
class PostListView(UserListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'feeds/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 10 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            liked = [i for i in Post.objects.all() if Like.objects.filter(user = self.request.user, post=i)]
            context['liked_post'] = liked
        return context
```

The key here is to inherit the `UserList` class and use `super()` in `get_context_data()`.